# Find the Laplace approximation of $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi }e^{x\cos(\theta )}d \theta$ for $ x \to \infty$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, laplace-method

Let's have integral
$$
I(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{x\cos(\theta )}d \theta, \quad x \to +\infty .  
$$
How to use Laplace approximation for this integral and find first two summands of asymptotic expansion?

**Edit:**

$$
I(x) = 2\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \limits_{0}^{\pi}e^{xcos(\theta )}d \theta = \left|z^2 = 1 - cos(\theta ), \quad d\theta = \frac{2dz}{\sqrt{2 - z^2}}\right| = 
$$
$$
=4e^{x}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \limits_{0}^{2} e^{-xz^2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2 - z^2}} = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 - z^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{z^2}{4 \sqrt{2}} + O(z^4)\right| = 
$$
$$
=\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{x}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-xz^2}\left( 1 + \frac{z^2}{4} + O(z^{4})\right)dz =  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \pi x}}e^{x}\left(1 + \frac{1}{8 x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right) .
$$

Comment: First, you're only interested in the *maxima* of $\cos \theta$ in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.  There is only one, and it's not on the boundary of the interval.  As for finding the first two terms of the asymptotic series, [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/596034/5531) outlines a few different methods for doing so.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : so I can only integrate by parts my integral expression, after that expand $cos(\theta )$ near maximum and then use Laplace method for each summand?

Comment: You don't need to integrate by parts.  Look at the answers to the question instead.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : so the convenient way is to expand $cos(\theta )$ near zero, then to make substitution $z^2 = 1 - cos(\theta ) \Rightarrow \theta = arccos (1 - z^2)$, then represent $d \theta $ through $dz$, after that - to integrate each summand, and, finally, to leave only the summands with first two orders of $x$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas : can you check my solution (I had updated the question's body)?

Comment: The method is perfect.  There's an issue with your second term at the end though.  Instead of $1/4x$ you should have $1/8x$.  Other than that it's right on.

Comment: Also don't forget your factor of $1/2\pi$ in front (from the definition of $I(x)$ at the top).

Comment: @AntonioVargas : thank you!